# Mutt, send email without saving it to Sent folder

Tags: mutt

I can manage to send email and save a copy using Mutt with its own ui.

```
mutt -s topic receiver
```

This will bring up mutt's interface to edit and send mail. It will first upload to imap server, and send the email through smtp server. There is a Fcc field in the header.

But When I use pure command line to send mail, say:

```
mutt -s topic receiver < foo
```

The mail is successfully sent, but no copy in my server's sent folder.
I check the debug log, the mail is not uploaded to imap server at all, just sent through smtp server.

I have tried to use my_hdr, but Fcc is not supported to be set.

fcc-hook is also tried, not use

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried putting the line

`set record=+accountname/sent`

into your .muttrc? i.e. where `accountname` is whatever you're calling your account and `sent` is the name of the sent emails mailbox, e.g. what I have in my .muttrc is

`set record = +mec07/"Sent Items"`

This command saves all the emails that I send into my "Sent Items" mailbox. Then my imap program saves it to the server.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue as well.

But after checking the [docs](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/wikis/MuttGuide/Folders#organizing-managing-emails) I was too blind to see that I had `set copy = no` set, therefore it wasn't saving any copies of sent emails. Commented that line, fired a message and it was successfully stored in the *Sent* folder.

In my `~/.muttrc` I have the following config so the delivered emails are successfully stored (I'm communicating with a Dovecot email server):

```
#set copy = no           
set postponed = "=Drafts"
set record = "=Sent"
```

Comment: Checking docs, but is there a way to `set copy = no` from the command-line? While the default to save to `sent` remains yes, when I run the interactive UI.